# How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file in Perl?

Tags: perl, file

People keep asking this question and I keep answering it with the same answer from [perlfaq5](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How_do_I_change_dele). Now it's something we can point to on Stackoverflow.

Comment: What's the point to repost `perlfaqN` here? Can't you just give a link to `perfaq5` http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change%2c-delete%2c-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file%2c-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file%3f to askers?

Comment: I always hate links. Websites go stale, URLs change, etc. I think Stackoverflow should capture information so it always have it. Remember, this is a long term project where the answer should be as good in three years as it is right now. A link doesn't guarantee that. Remember that www.perldoc.com used to be the preferred site for docs until it disappeared. That could happen to any site.

Comment: Also, see the meta thread where I asked about importing all the perlfaq: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24244/can-we-import-the-perlfaq-into-stackoverflow

Comment: @brian Did you get an official response from the StackOverflow team about the import of perlfaq ?

Comment: I think Jeff was going to defer to whatever people decided. I just haven't had time to do it yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Perl, how do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388304/in-perl-how-do-i-change-delete-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file-or-append-to-the-be)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Perl, how do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388304/in-perl-how-do-i-change-delete-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file-or-append-to-the-b)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [perlfaq5](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How_do_I_change_dele):

The basic idea of inserting, changing, or deleting a line from a text file involves reading and printing the file to the point you want to make the change, making the change, then reading and printing the rest of the file. Perl doesn't provide random access to lines (especially since the record input separator, `$/`, is mutable), although modules such as [Tie::File](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie::File) can fake it.

A Perl program to do these tasks takes the basic form of opening a file, printing its lines, then closing the file:

```
open my $in,  '<',  $file      or die "Can't read old file: $!";
open my $out, '>', "$file.new" or die "Can't write new file: $!";

while( <$in> )
    {
    print $out $_;
    }

close $out;
```

Within that basic form, add the parts that you need to insert, change, or delete lines.

To prepend lines to the beginning, print those lines before you enter the loop that prints the existing lines.

```
open my $in,  '<',  $file      or die "Can't read old file: $!";
open my $out, '>', "$file.new" or die "Can't write new file: $!";

print $out "# Add this line to the top\n"; # <--- HERE'S THE MAGIC

while( <$in> )
    {
    print $out $_;
    }

close $out;
```

To change existing lines, insert the code to modify the lines inside the `while` loop. In this case, the code finds all lowercased versions of "perl" and uppercases them. It happens for every line, so be sure that you're supposed to do that on every line!

```
open my $in,  '<',  $file      or die "Can't read old file: $!";
open my $out, '>', "$file.new" or die "Can't write new file: $!";

print $out "# Add this line to the top\n";

while( <$in> )
    {
    s/\b(perl)\b/Perl/g;
    print $out $_;
    }

close $out;
```

To change only a particular line, the input line number, `$.`, is useful. First read and print the lines up to the one you want to change. Next, read the single line you want to change, change it, and print it. After that, read the rest of the lines and print those:

```
while( <$in> )   # print the lines before the change
    {
    print $out $_;
    last if $. == 4; # line number before change
    }

my $line = <$in>;
$line =~ s/\b(perl)\b/Perl/g;
print $out $line;

while( <$in> )   # print the rest of the lines
    {
    print $out $_;
    }
```

To skip lines, use the looping controls. The `next` in this example skips comment lines, and the `last` stops all processing once it encounters either `__END__` or `__DATA__`.

```
while( <$in> )
    {
    next if /^\s+#/;             # skip comment lines
    last if /^__(END|DATA)__$/;  # stop at end of code marker
    print $out $_;
    }
```

Do the same sort of thing to delete a particular line by using `next` to skip the lines you don't want to show up in the output. This example skips every fifth line:

```
while( <$in> )
    {
    next unless $. % 5;
    print $out $_;
    }
```

If, for some odd reason, you really want to see the whole file at once rather than processing line-by-line, you can slurp it in (as long as you can fit the whole thing in memory!):

```
open my $in,  '<',  $file      or die "Can't read old file: $!"
open my $out, '>', "$file.new" or die "Can't write new file: $!";

my @lines = do { local $/; <$in> }; # slurp!

    # do your magic here

print $out @lines;
```

Modules such as [File::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Slurp) and [Tie::File](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie::File) can help with that too. If you can, however, avoid reading the entire file at once. Perl won't give that memory back to the operating system until the process finishes.

You can also use Perl one-liners to modify a file in-place. The following changes all 'Fred' to 'Barney' in `inFile.txt`, overwriting the file with the new contents. With the `-p` switch, Perl wraps a `while` loop around the code you specify with `-e`, and `-i` turns on in-place editing. The current line is in `$_`. With `-p`, Perl automatically prints the value of `$_` at the end of the loop. See [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) for more details.

```
perl -pi -e 's/Fred/Barney/' inFile.txt
```

To make a backup of `inFile.txt`, give `-i` a file extension to add:

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/Fred/Barney/' inFile.txt
```

To change only the fifth line, you can add a test checking `$.`, the input line number, then only perform the operation when the test passes:

```
perl -pi -e 's/Fred/Barney/ if $. == 5' inFile.txt
```

To add lines before a certain line, you can add a line (or lines!) before Perl prints `$_`:

```
perl -pi -e 'print "Put before third line\n" if $. == 3' inFile.txt
```

You can even add a line to the beginning of a file, since the current line prints at the end of the loop:

```
perl -pi -e 'print "Put before first line\n" if $. == 1' inFile.txt
```

To insert a line after one already in the file, use the `-n` switch. It's just like `-p` except that it doesn't print `$_` at the end of the loop, so you have to do that yourself. In this case, print `$_` first, then print the line that you want to add.

```
perl -ni -e 'print; print "Put after fifth line\n" if $. == 5' inFile.txt
```

To delete lines, only print the ones that you want.

```
perl -ni -e 'print unless /d/' inFile.txt

    ... or ...

perl -pi -e 'next unless /d/' inFile.txt
```

Comment: Just wondering, why doesn't it work when we write `perl -pie...`?

Comment: -pie doesn't work because the -i expects an argument, and it thinks the 'e' belongs to it.

Comment: The last variant: `perl -pi -e 'next unless /d/' inFile.txt` does not work, and is no longer shown in [perlfaq](https://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change-delete-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file).  Some discussion in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4388309/411282)