# append a text on the top of the file

Tags: shell, perl

I want to add a text on the top of  my data.txt file, this code add the text at the end of the file. how I can modify this code to write the text on the top of my data.txt file. thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
open (MYFILE, '>>data.txt');
print MYFILE "Title\n";
close (MYFILE)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322140/how-do-i-change-delete-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file-or-append-to-the-beginning-o

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
 perl -pi -e 'print "Title\n" if $. == 1' data.text
```

Comment: Excellent one-liner, but it should be noted that this still loops through the file line-by-line and prints each one back to the original file. See http://oreilly.com/pub/h/73 for a great write-up on this use case.

Comment: how to add one line to each file of file globs? like *.txt

Answer (score 8):

Your syntax is <strike>slightly off</strike> deprecated (thanks, Seth):

```
open(MYFILE, '>>', "data.txt") or die $!;
```

You will have to make a full pass through the file and write out the desired data before the existing file contents:

```
open my $in,  '<',  $file      or die "Can't read old file: $!";
open my $out, '>', "$file.new" or die "Can't write new file: $!";

print $out "# Add this line to the top\n"; # <--- HERE'S THE MAGIC

while( <$in> ) {
    print $out $_;
}
close $out;
close $in;

unlink($file);
rename("$file.new", $file);
```

(gratuitously stolen from the [Perl FAQ](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How_do_I_change_dele), then modified)

This will process the file line-by-line so that on large files you don't chew up a ton of memory. But, it's not exactly fast.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 8):

There is a much simpler one-liner to prepend a block of text to every file. Let's say you have a set of files named **body1**, **body2**, **body3**, etc, to which you want to prepend a block of text contained in a file called **header**:

```
cat header | perl -0 -i -pe 'BEGIN {$h = <STDIN>}; print $h' body*
```

Comment: Just found out that there is 1 problem with this code: it does not insert the header to an empty file.

Answer (score 2):

Appending to the top is normally called prepending.

```
open(M,"<","data.txt");
@m = <M>;
close(M);
open(M,">","data.txt");
print M "foo\n";
print M @m;
close(M);
```

Alternately open data.txt- for writing and then move data.txt- to data.txt after the close, which has the benefit of being atomic so interruptions cannot leave the data.txt file truncated.

Answer (score 2):

See the [Perl FAQ Entry](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change%2c-delete%2c-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file%2c-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file%3f) on this topic

Answer (score -1):

perl -ni -e 'print "Title\n" $.==1' filename               , this print the answer once